# UIImage 1x, 2x, 3x Resolution best practice

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I've finished coding my first iOS App I intend to submit for distribution to the App Store, to support all iPhone sizes. I'm working on the image assets and want to ensure I'm doing things the best way possible. Can I just use the highest resolution image I can get, and supply that in the assets catalog x3 box - Or, do I have to scale down the image to suit x2 as well?

Images will be used at their largest in a 1:1 scale UIImageview, with the largest supported device being the latest iPhone 12 Pro Max which has a resolution of 2778x1284 pixels.

If my ImageView is set 16pts from leading edge, and 16pts from trailing edge at a 1:1 ratio, by my calculations the max size will be 1252px x 1252px for the ImageView, and smaller on the other supported devices.

Can I just ensure I supply image assets that are 1252px x 1252px, or larger, into the x3 box, and be done with it? Or scale down the largest image for x2 devices and provide that also?

Answer (score 1):

Better to use all 3 sizes. That may help you to optimize and reduce the app size.

refer this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size/doing_basic_optimization_to_reduce_your_app_s_size

Use this to generate icons of different sizes. : https://appicon.co/#image-sets

Comment: 1x is not needed considering that there is no device currently supported that still have seen scale at 1x